# Sorting Algorithm compression

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Let A and B be two algorithms that solve the same problem.
Claim: If A is faster than B, both in the worst case and in the average case, then,
necessarily, A is faster than B, in the best case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider merge sort vs insertion sort. Merge sort is always `O(n log n)` in best, average, and worst cases. Insertion sort is `O(n^2)` in average and wort cases; however it is `O(n)` in the best case.